# I'm running the same code on different device but they don't have the same output

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm designing the ui for the application and when I run the code using other device, the output is perfectly fine, just like when I tried to run the code in my mobile using Pydroid 3 and my friend's laptop, but when I run my code using my own PC the code is working but the output is not the same, the display seems to be out of place, btw the code I used is the same, I did not change anything.

[The fist pic is the output using my own pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnmh1.png)

[The second pic should be the output of the code that I run(it's the same code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGyvL.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience using Pydroid, but I would guess based on the devices you're using that the sizing is the issue. A mobile screen is very different in size to a computer screen. If you have your code optimized for one and not the other, it will probably look like that. Similar to website development and how you have to account for different screen sizes. Hope this helps. Also, here's a link to another stackoverflow question that seems to be similar to yours: [Can you obtain physical size of device in kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857346/can-you-obtain-physical-size-of-device-in-kivy)